# How to hide my WHOIS Information with Plesk on a Linux server?

Tags: linux, plesk, whois

i want to hide my WHOIS Information and my linux server is running PLESK. Does somebody know anything for getting this done?

Comment: AFAIK the only real way to do this is to register your domain with a registrar which has an explicit option for whois privacy.

Comment: @ChristopheD thank you! then its the only way :(